# Disable new windows auto opening in background

Tags: window

Skype contact list, Home folder, etc.
How to open them in foreground?

Comment: Do these windows *always* open behind other windows, for you?

Comment: It happens from time to time

Comment: Same here with e.g. Skype. It seems to be application dependent: Happens *always* with Skype, but never with e.g. LibreOffice. So either an application falls into the "background category" (then it is always reproducable) or not (then it always works fine).

Comment: Btw: for those who think it rarely happens, I just found [this thread on UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1911406) talking about it in detail. Unfortunately without finding a solution -- but exactly the same software affected: Skype, Home folder, plus Tomboy.

Answer (score 16):

Me too I suffered from app window shyness. I found how to fix it, though.

1. get `compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Press <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> and type `ccsm`
3. click on *"General Options"*
4. Select the *"Focus and Raise Behaviour"* tab
5. Check *"Auto-raise"* and set *"Focus Prevention"* level to *Off*

That fixed things up for me.  Hope it does for you as well.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me. For example Transmission, or KMahjongg always open behind any other open window. I'm using Unity-2D with 12.04LTS.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in 16.04 without installing ccsm?

Comment: Do we have to restart after doing it?

Comment: Follow what MattBAustinTX suggested, but don't forget to restart (or at least log-out so your desktop environment restarts).

Answer (score 1):

Besids `ccsm` I have made a made `gnome-tweaks` reset and a `reboot`.

Now it works as expected.

[Picture how to reset gnome-tweaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTrY3.png)