# How do I get a Nautilus shortcut to open on top of everything?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, directory, shortcuts, top

I've made a nautilus short cut for almost all of my common folders. But when I press the keys to use the shortcut the folder do open, but they only open in the background. I still have to make a few clicks to see them infront of me.

I want to configure my shortcuts so the nautilus folders show up on top of everything. How can I do that?

Currently I am only using the basic System Settings keyboard shortcut function.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162757/disable-new-windows-auto-opening-in-background  check this link, this should solve your problem

Comment: wouldn't creating a Unity quicklist work for you better than a number of keyboard shortcuts? The window will be automatically raised as a side effect.

Comment: I edited my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/507953/keyboard-shortcut-for-opening-a-new-window-in-ubuntu/508063#508063 to cover your question as well ("Edit (2014-11-11")